# Why does my XML file output to the page?

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse an xml file and add its contents to a database.

Here is the code..

```
function generateDeck($userid, $db) {

    if (!$xml = simplexml_load_file('deckList.xml')) {
        trigger_error('Error reading XML file', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    foreach ($xml as $card) {

        $id = $userid;
        $card_id = $card->card_id;
        $box_num = $card->box_num;
        $order = $card->order_num;

        $insert = "INSERT INTO decks (id, card_id, box_num, order_num) VALUES ('$id','$card_id','$box_num','$order')";
        $select = "SELECT * FROM decks ORDER BY order_num";

        mysqli_query($db, $insert) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysqli_error($db));
        mysqli_query($db, $select) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysqli_error($db));

    }

    mysqli_close($db);
}
```

here is the xml

```
<deck>
   <card>
      <card_id>baby</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>1</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>selectBaby</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>2</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>bed</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>3</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>selectBed</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>4</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>book</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>5</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>selectBook</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>6</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>cup</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>7</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>selectCup</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>8</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>cupboard</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>9</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>selectCupboard</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>10</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>daddy</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>11</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>selectDaddy</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>12</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>eating</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>13</order>
   </card> 
   <card>
      <card_id>mummy</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>14</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>selectMummy</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>15</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>plate</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>16</order>
   </card>
   <card>
      <card_id>selectPlate</card_id>
      <box_num>1</box_num>
      <order>17</order>
   </card>

.....


</deck>
```

However, every line of the XML prints to the screen. :-/ I am calling this function from another php file by using two lines..

```
//Generate new deck for new user
include('generateDeck.php');
generateDeck($user, $db);
```

Does anyone know why the xml contents is being output to the screen? My output is..

> baby 1 1 selectBaby 1 2 bed 1 3 selectBed 1 4 book 1 5
>   selectBook 1 6 cup 1 7 selectCup 1 8 cupboard 1 9 selectCupboard 1 10
>   daddy 1 11 selectDaddy 1 12 eating 1 13 mummy 1 14 selectMummy 1 15
>   plate 1 16 selectPlate 1 17 shoe 1 18 selectShoe 1 19 table 1 20
>   selectTable 1 21 walking 1 22 selectWalking 1 23 dogNose 1 24
>   selectDogNose 1 25 teddyEars 1 26 selectTeddyEars 1 27 ActivityOne 1
>   28 ActivityTwo 1 29 ActivityThree 1 30 ActivityFour 1 31 ActivityFive
>   1 32 ActivitySix 1 33

The browser is rendering

```
<deck>
   <card>

   </card>
   <card>

   </card>
   <card>

   </card>

.....

</deck>
```

Confirmed in Firebug

Thanks.

(Edited to reflect change to reserved word usage (order *is now* order_num)

Comment: anything else in 'generateDeck.php'?

Comment: I can't understand why you are using select query inside the loop ?

Comment: The data represents a set of flashcards and they must be ordered by there order index.  That's why im using a select statement.  in other news my insert statement doesn't work either.. I get an error.. SQL Error 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order) VALUES ('1','baby','1','1')' at line 1 There is no other code inside generateDeck.php

Comment: OH.. its inside the loop.. I gotcha.. I should move it out right..?

Comment: moved it outside now, but my SQL statement still doesn't work.

Comment: please show your XML, if it is complex, a instructive and valid snippet of it!

Comment: I did notice that later on actually :) Still no change in my XML being output to the screen though :-/

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the entire XML file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31697/discussion-between-david-folksman-and-prix)